# PHP Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, mysql, wpdb

I have woocommerce website which give database error from 4-5 days. I checked the error log, the error is:

> **PHP Warning**: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=31071 in /home/goldenwiggles/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2008

**and my hosting account is also suspended** can anyone suggest me what to do in case.

Comment: first thing should be talk to your hosting provider and discuss the matter

Comment: my hosting provider send me this: kindly refer the below mysql logs:

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info |
+------+------------------+-----------+--------------------------+---------+------+---------------
| 4377 | goldenwi_gold | localhost | goldenwi_petfood_store | Sleep | 2 | | |
| 4378 | goldenwi_gold | localhost | goldenwi_petfood_store | Sleep | 19 | | |
| 4379 | goldenwi_gold | localhost | goldenwi_petfood_store | Sleep | 3 | | |

Comment: not that. do a discussion.

Comment: About what.......

Comment: your problem, suspension. they'll surely provide better help other than just sending you some logs. go for technical or sales support

Comment: Ok thanks.............................

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you are getting the "Error while sending QUERY packet' message. The best we can tell, this has to do with the max_allowed_packet_size. This should be able to be set via the php.ini file. You may find more information at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet) regarding the issue.

Source: Branex

Comment: how can i edit mycnf file with cmd

Comment: Login to your server via SSH.
To edit the MySQL settings with nano type the following: nano /etc/my.cnf. Note! ...
Find the line to edit. ...
Enter Ctrl + O to "WriteOut" or save the settings.
Then Ctrl + X to exit.
Restart MySQL by typing the following. service mysql restart

Comment: actually  i am unable to connect via ssh putty is showing network error connection refused